# DryWetMIDI receive a NoteOn by release a Keyboard key

Tags: c#, midi

I use DryWetMIDI which works fine with some Keyboards.

With my Johannus organ DryWetMIDI InputDevice receives a NoteOn message when I release a key!
I've checked the Keyboards messages with Midi-OX. The Keyboard sends the right messages (NoteOn/NoteOff) when I press and release a key.

How can this happen? What's going wrong?

Comment: Please show the messages in Midi-OX.

Comment: I'm the author of DryWetMIDI. Please show log of incoming events using `EventReceived` event handler. I suppose those Note On messages have zero velocity. DWM by default doesn't process incoming events. So Note On with zero velocity wll arrive to you as Note On with zero velocity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That helps me. If I release a key, I receive a NoteOn-Message with velocity 0. If I press a key the NoteOn-Message has a velocity of 64.
Thank you very much for this tip!

Comment: I see settings.SilentNoteOnPolicy what is NoteOn. If this NoteOff and velocity == 0 than DWM creates a NoteOff Message.

Comment: The InputDevice-Constructor set this: _bytesToMidiEventConverter.ReadingSettings.SilentNoteOnPolicy = SilentNoteOnPolicy.NoteOn;
Thats my problem. I commented this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting the answer based on comments.

Your device sending Note Off as Note On with velocity of zero which is common way to encode Note Off. But DryWetMIDI doesn't process incoming events by default, so you see raw messages as a device sends them.

Version 5.2.1 of the library provides [`SilentNoteOnPolicy`](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/api/Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Multimedia.InputDevice.html#Melanchall_DryWetMidi_Multimedia_InputDevice_SilentNoteOnPolicy) property within `InputDevice`. Setting the policy to `NoteOff` tells DWM automatically transform Note On with zero velocity to Note Off.